# Errors: npm not installing packages

Tags: angularjs, node.js

```
C:\Users\Wallay Masroof\Desktop\quickstart-master>npm install
npm WARN deprecated express@2.5.11: express 2.x series is deprecated
npm WARN deprecated connect@1.9.2: connect 1.x series is deprecated
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! shasum check failed for C:\Users\WALLAY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-11652-be3fdaea\registry.npmjs.org\jsprim\-\jsprim-1.4.1.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: 313e66bc1e5cc06e438bc1b7499c2e5c56acb6a2
npm ERR! Actual:   b2b66a6002872c52d4a30a7f8208588eef541e5d
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/jsprim/-/jsprim-1.4.1.tgz
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Wallay Masroof\Desktop\quickstart-master\npm-debug.log
```

whenever I try to install npm, it shows me this error. it is not even installing in angular quickstart I cloned from GitHub.

Comment: Is `node` properly installed? Run `node -v` in a terminal and see what it outputs.

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu yes it is installed and node -v shows v6.11.4

Comment: What does this file contain? `C:\Users\Wallay Masroof\Desktop\quickstart-master\npm-debug.log`

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu I cloned the Angular Quickstart form GitHub. it was present in it.

Comment: No that's the error log that has information about the error. Can you post it here?

Answer (score 0):

I tryed to install on my fedora an every thing went right, I also tryed to install on a windows 10 and everuthing went well too.

I recommend that you clean your npm cache with

```
npm cache clean
```

And if Necessary

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Or a more "violent" way by deletting npm-cache folder at:

```
%AppData%/npm-cache
```

Comment: I cleaned the cache but I'm still getting the same error.. :(

Comment: I saw a similar eror when the connection was faulty and the file was getting corrupted during the download.

Comment: I was reading the documentation and you could try to clean your c:\windows\temp as npm store some temporary files there too.

Comment: Ok, I talked with a friend of mine that uses windows and you will need reinstall npm from zero, aparently is something with the latest update that screws  it.

Comment: I think internet was the reason behind all this. it installed successfully today on my university internet. Thank you so much for your time . :)